# Meteor autoForm autosave not reflecting in template

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

Using Meteor's phenomenal [autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) from **aldeed**.

I have a custom form using autoForm that has the autosave on.

```
{{#autoForm collection="people" id=formId type="update" class="update" doc=. autosave=true template="autoupdate"}}
```

I have created a custom input template, the relevant part of which looks like this:

```
<template name="afInputText_autoupdate">
  <input type="text" value="{{this.value}}" {{atts}}/><span class="display-value">{{this.value}}</span>
</template>
```

The `.display-value` span is shown and the input is hidden by default (using css), and when clicked on the input is shown and the span is hidden.

Everything works as expected including the autosave feature except that the value in the `.display-value` span does not update automatically as I would expect.

I suspect there's something about the object used to create the form not being subscribed to the document in question. I don't have the understanding of the inner workings of Meteor yet to figure this out (I've tried).

Could someone kindly point me in the right direction to get that value to update?